# show only one element and rest should reset in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to show only one element of a div and reset all other elements in an array with the help of the useState hook.

I've made an initial state in the form of boolean array representing the show value (true to show and false to hide) for each element. An onClick event handler is passed on each element, which will change all the values of the array as true and will change the only element clicked as false at its index. I've attached the code below. Also, `props.id` contains the index/key of the component.

Code

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import myComponent from "./Components/myComponents.js";

const Add = (props) =>{
    const [showVals,changeShowVals]=useState([true,true,true,true,true,true,true]);

    const displayHandler=(id)=>{
        const x=id;
        const vals=new Array(7).fill(true);
        vals[x]=!vals[x];
        changeShowVals(vals);
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {showVals[props.id]?
                <myComponent onClick={()=>displayHandler(props.id)}/>:null}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Add;
```

Comment: you need to hide the component on click. is it ?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to show one of the components that is in the array at position `props.id`. Your code is supposed to hide it when you click on it, which it looks like it already is doing, and any previously clicked elements would be reset to true (shown).

Your title says "show only one element and rest should hide", whilst you're talking about the "only clicked element" in your question. 

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, I want to show the clicked component and reset previously clicked elements.

Comment: The problem in this solution is that, when I click on the first show/hide button it shows the component which is correct, but when I click the second show/hide button it should hide the second component and show the first component which in this case it doesn't seem to do so.  @SarunUK

Comment: @SarunUK I am already achieving this result with my code

Comment: Do you mean when you Click the second it should hide the first one, and show the second one? And not the other way around, since the first one is already shown? When you Click the second one, are both shown? Or just the one you clicked first?

Comment: @Sodnarts No, quite opposite, If I click the second element it should hide only the second element but should show all the elements irrespective of the fact whether they are previously shown or hidden

Comment: this is what you are expecting - https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-goldwasser-mlnk5?file=/src/App.js:0-891

Comment: @SarunUK Yes, but can you tell me what's wrong with my code. Why isn't it working?

Comment: What is id here? Are you rely on the index?

Comment: @SarunUK Yup did it just now, but no change.

Comment: No it wont work you have already creating a new instance

Comment: vals[x]=!vals[x]; -> I think id is nothing but the index. It will vary based on the show/hide

Comment: Let me try with your code. Give me sometime

Comment: @SarunUK but passing in the changeShowVals to update the state, so it should work right???

Comment: Could you please provide codesandbox for your changes ?

Comment: Yeah, I'll provide you right away

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this code, I tried to tune it down from my original code, it seems I messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the answer based on your code.

You are not defining the click handler for the `Red` component.

My Component:-

```
import React from "react";

function MyComponent({ onClick, number }) {
  const style = {
    height: "20px",
    width: "20px",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    margin: "4px",
    cursor: "pointer"
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={() => onClick(number)} style={style}>
      {number}
    </div>
  );
}
export default MyComponent;
```

App Component:-

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
    import Red from "./red";
    import Green from "./green";
    
    const App = () => {
      const [showVals, changeShowVals] = useState([
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true
      ]);
    
      const displayHandler = (index) => {
        const vals = new Array(7).fill(true);
        vals[index] = !vals[index];
        changeShowVals(vals);
      };
    
      const number = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
      return number.map((ele, i) =>
        showVals[i] ? (
          <div onClick={() => displayHandler(ele)}>
            <Red number={ele} key={ele + " red"} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Green number={ele} key={ele + " green"} />
        )
      );
    };
    export default App;
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8lgc7?file=/App.js:0-684

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-s1kdo?file=/App.js I've made some changes, I want to click on red component so that it will become green and if clicked on any other red component previous green component should become red and clicked component should become green.

Comment: I have updated the code - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8lgc7?file=/App.js

Comment: Reason is you are not defining the click handler for the Red component. Updated the answer

Comment: So does that mean I've to make an extra div for each component when trying to handle the event listener?

Comment: Your component should handle that -->  return <div style={style}>{props.number}</div> - add a click handler inside the `Red` component

Comment: Updated again. please have a look

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Works exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: Need at least 15 rep. As soon as I'll get it, I'll for sure upvote it.